# Формирование DOM с помощью innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при формирование DOM происходит так:

```
<div id="result">
  <div class="block"></div>
  a=5
</div>
```

Хотя я ожидаю видеть:

```
<div id="result">
  <div class="block">a=5</div>
</div>
```

Вот сам код:

```
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
  var a = 5;
  result.innerHTML += `<div class="block">`;
  if (a==5)
    result.innerHTML += `a=5`;
  else
    result.innerHTML += `a!=5`;
  result.innerHTML += `</div>`;
</script>
```

---

Как правильно сформировать этот фрагмент, чтобы увидеть то, что я ожидаю и почему это работает неправильно?

Comment: Вообще, чем меньше насиловать страницу с innerHTML - тем лучше) Поэтому в идеале надо заранее всё собрать в виде строки, в одну переменную, а уже потом добавить её в виде HTML. При этом, когда вы пишете `innerHTML += ...` — каждый раз весь HTML в этом блоке заново переписывается. Можете поискать про `appendChild, before, after, insertAdjacentHTML`.

Comment: Скорее всего, валидатор хрома автоматом закрыл неполный тег при первой вставке, а последнюю выкинул, посчитав лишней

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этот момент

```
result.innerHTML+=`<div class="block">`;
```

элемент `div` с `class="block"` уже создан.

А это

```
result.innerHTML+=`</div>`;
```

ничего не делает.

---

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
  var a = 5;
  var inner = "";
  inner += `<div class="block">`;
  if (a==5)
    inner += `a=5`;
  else
    inner += `a!=5`;
  inner += `</div>`;
  result.innerHTML = inner;
</script>
```